# OS X - El Capitan Mouse Problem (After Alt-Tab)

Tags: starcraft-2, mouse

I am using OS X El Capitan. When I opened the first time StarCraft 2, I have no problem. But, When I did Alt-Tab and returned the game, Mouse cursor has lag and is seen double.

How Can I solve this problem ?

My El-Capitan config is here:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this still happen if you play in Windowed (Fullscreen) mode?

Answer (score 4):

The issue you're describing shouldn't happen, no matter what configuration you're using. Therefore, I assume it's a bug in StarCraft 2. You can only wait for Blizzard to fix that bug for the OSX version of the game.

Luckily, most if not all bugs related to alt-tabbing can be resolved by playing in windowed mode. StarCraft 2 offers a `Windowed (Fullscreen)` mode, which looks exactly like Fullscreen mode.

[image: Windowed (Fullscreen) under Graphics options]

However, there are a few things you need to keep in mind when playing in `Windowed (Fullscreen)` mode:

- Your game will have to render via the compositing window manager (DWM on Windows, Quartz on OSX), instead of running directly on your GPU. This might negatively impact your performance, though it should be minimal on modern hardware.
- Some screen capturing software might not work, while others might. In the case of Windows 10, *Nvidia ShadowPlay* only works in true Fullscreen mode, whereas the Xbox app's *Game DVR* feature only works for windowed games (things may have changed by now, though). I'm not an expert on OSX, but I expect similar limitations to exist there too.
- StarCraft 2 does not allow you to set a resolution in `Windowed (Fullscreen)` mode. You'll have to play on your native resolution instead. If you need to play on a lower resolution due to performance reasons, playing in `Windowed (Fullscreen)` ***will*** have a negative impact on your performance.
  Luckily, not every game is like that. Some games will allow you to set a different resolution, but the window will be shrunk accordingly; others (like MGS 5) will maintain the same window size, but render at the resolution you defined.

In return, playing in `Windowed (Fullscreen)` means your game will behave just like any other app on your PC, so alt-tabbing should no longer cause any issues.

Comment: I found that my problem. I have been using "SmoothMouse" which is 3rd party app. It occurs for SmoothMouse. But I could not fix this problem.